# MongoDB Spring Data gives No property '$$value' found on class exception

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

> ```
> //Sample Collection
> {
>   //fields
>   "roleList" : [ROLE_1, ROLE_2, ROLE_3],
>   "siteList" : [
>   {
>       "role" : ROLE_1,
>       //fields
>   },
>   {
>       "role" : ROLE_2,
>       //fields
>   },
>   ]
> }
>
> //Expected Output
> {
>   //fields
>   "roleDiff":[ROLE_3] // roleList subtracted by set of roles present in siteList
> }
> ```

> ```
> //Script that works with Studio 3t
> db.getCollection("SAMPLE_COLLECTION").aggregate(
>
>   // Pipeline
>   [
>       // Stage 1
>       {
>           $project: {
>               "roleList":1,
>               "siteRoles":{$ifNull: [{$reduce:{
>                   input:"$siteList",
>                   initialValue:[],
>                   in:{$setUnion:["$$value", {
>           "$split": ["$$this.role", " "]}]}
>               }
>               }, []]}
>           }
>       },
>
>       // Stage 2
>       {
>           $project: {
>               "roleDiff":{ $setDifference:["$roleList", "$siteRoles"]
>               }
>           }
>       },
>   ],
>
>   // Options
>   {
>
>   }
>
>   // Created with Studio 3T, the IDE for MongoDB - https://studio3t.com/
>
> );
> ```

```
ArrayOperators.Reduce reduce = ArrayOperators.Reduce.arrayOf("siteList").withInitialValue(Collections.EMPTY_SET)
            .reduce(SetOperators.SetUnion.arrayAsSet(StringOperators.valueOf("$$this.role").split(" ")).union(ArrayOperators.Reduce.Variable.VALUE.getTarget()));
ProjectionOperation projectionOperationOne = Aggregation.project().andInclude(/*Some fields,*/ "roleList").and(ConditionalOperators.ifNull(reduce).then(Collections.EMPTY_LIST)).as("siteRoles");    
ProjectionOperation projectionOperationTwo = Aggregation.project().andInclude(/*Some fields*/).and(SetOperators.SetDifference.arrayAsSet("roleList").differenceTo("siteRoles")).as("roleDiff");
Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(projectionOperationOne, projectionOperationTwo);
AggregationResults<SiteDiff> siteDiff = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, SampleCollection.class, SiteDiff.class);
```

The Java code above thows exception
org.springframework.data.mapping.context.InvalidPersistentPropertyPath: No property '$$value' found on class Did you mean: ?
The query works fine with Studio3T. My intention here is to get the difference between 2 String arrays "roleList" and "siteRoles" along with some other fields in the record.
"siteRoles" has to be derived from "siteList" which is an array of object. Since $addToSet works only with $group operation, I'm finding it difficult to extract the role from "siteList". I used reduce here combining it with setUnion. There problem was role is a string and I had to convert it to array. Only way I could find was to use $split and use " " as delimiter as I'm sure role will not have space.
Finally, the script worked in studio3t but the java version is not getting executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you refer to a field in an embedded array, it should give you the entire array of those values.

The aggregation should only need 1 stage:

```
{$project: {roleDiff: { $setDifference: ["$roleList","$siteList.role"]}}}
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot. I know my previous code was a very complicated one. But just to have a clear idea on spring data, do you know why that java code didn't work even though the script gave the expected result in Studio3T?

Comment: I suspect there was a typo somewhere.  Java shouldn't be trying to evaluate the $$value as anything other than a string, so there is probably an extra or missing quote.